# error message when adding snippets package to my R library

Tags: r, geospatial

I'm trying to make use of the R package "snippets." So, I seem to have installed it ok:

```
> install.packages("snippets", , "http://rforge.net/")
```

But then, when I go to add it to my library, I get the following error message:

```
> library(snippets)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘snippets’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘png’
```

I'm lost after that. Anyone know what to do?

Jerry

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your error. Works fine for me. Maybe add `dependencies=TRUE` in `install.packages()`.

Comment: I was told that maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm on a public computer at the university. I was told to try it from my laptop when I get home instead. Will see if that works. Haven't tried it yet. Thanks for trying to assist. Will let you know how it goes.